# Проблема с анимацией в unity2d

Tags: unity3d

Сделал анимацию и её переключение. Анимация бега спокойно работает, но с анимацией прыжка беды. Она просто не переключается. Вот скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вместо GetKey, лучше используй GetAxis("Horizontal").
Вместо bool "jump" в аниматоре создай trigger "jump" и используй SetTrigger, который будет активировать прыжок один раз во время нажатии клавиши прыжка.

Comment: От этого смысл не поменяется. Триггер пробовал, такая же беда. Ничего не выходит

Comment: также пробовал изменить анимацию, но такое ощущение, что больше 1 нельзя добавить...